# Insert Dynamic Section Headers in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which i want to add the section headers dynamically as the user clicks add button. The user should also be able to delete the headers if they dont need it. Under each header the user should be able to add relevant list of items. And apart from that the user should be able to insert rows dynamically under selected section only. Please suggest some ideas to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance.

Comment: - 1 for not offering any input into the solutions you have tried

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by removing and then adding that section again, this will cause a call to `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`

Assume your section index is 0:

```
BOOL shouldShowHeader;
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    shouldShowHeader ? @"Your Header" : nil;
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    shouldShowHeader = !shouldShowHeader;
    NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteSections:set withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView insertSections:set withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Footer works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell for dynamic section header. Keep a flag and set to 0 initially. When User clickes on button in that buttonClick method set flag to 1 and reload tableView.

```
          -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
          {
                  if(flag)
                       return aView;//alloc init aView and return.
                  else
                       return nil.
          }
```

Similarly for dynamic rows have a array and numberOfRows be array.count.
On click of button insert one more item in array and reload Table.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks on button in this method set a flag and reload your tableview and then do it..

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(flag)
    {
        UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 30)];
        return headerView;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

and you can delete header in table view like this......

If you want to remove the table's header view, just set the myTable.tableHeaderView property to nil. If what you have is actually a section header, then you need to return nil from the viewForHeaderInSection method and call [myTableView reloadData]

and i hope this will work fine.